# How to add a confidence interval to a Circular Histogram (von Mises distribution)

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I have time data, and I want to plot the frequency per hour on a 24hr clock.

The data are transformed to `circular`, and the estimates for 'periodic mean' `mu` and 'concentration' `kappa` are calculated with `mle.vonmises()`.

The graph is generated with `ggplot2`, using `geom_hist()` and `coord_polar()`. The periodic mean is drawn on the plot with a simple call to `geom_vline()`.

**Question**

I want to draw a **confidence interval** of 95% around the mean. Then, I would like to visually check whether a given timestamp (e.g. "22:00:00") lies within the CI or not.
How do I do this with a von mises distribution and ggplot2?

The code below shows how far I got.

The data

```
timestamps <- c("08:43:48", "09:17:52", "12:56:22", "12:27:32", "10:59:23", 
                "07:22:45", "11:13:59", "10:13:26", "10:07:01", "06:09:56", 
                "12:43:17", "07:07:35", "09:36:44", "10:45:00", "08:27:36", 
                "07:55:35", "11:32:56", "13:18:35", "11:09:51", "09:46:33", 
                "06:59:12", "10:19:36", "09:39:47", "09:39:46", "18:23:54")
```

The code

```
library(lubridate)
library(circular)
library(ggplot2)

## Convert from char to hours
timestamps_hrs <- as.numeric(hms(timestamps)) / 3600

## Convert to class circular
timestamps_hrs_circ <- circular(timestamps_hrs, units = "hours", template = "clock24")

## Estimate the periodic mean and the concentration 
## from the von Mises distribution
estimates <- mle.vonmises(timestamps_hrs_circ)
periodic_mean <- estimates$mu %% 24
concentration <- estimates$kappa

## Clock plot // Circular Histogram
clock01 <- ggplot(data.frame(timestamps_hrs_circ), aes(x = timestamps_hrs_circ)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 24), colour = "blue", fill = "lightblue") +
  coord_polar() + 
  scale_x_continuous("", limits = c(0, 24), breaks = seq(0, 24), minor_breaks = NULL) +
  theme_light()

clock01

## Add the periodic_mean
clock01 + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(periodic_mean), color = "red", linetype = 3, size = 1.25)
```

This yields the following graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found an approximation of the solution. As we know the parameters `mu` and `kappa` (resp. the periodic mean and the concentration), we know the distribution. This, in turn, means we know the densities of given timestamps, and we can calculate the cutoff for the 95% confidence level.

Once we have that, we can generate the timestamps for every minute of a day. We transform the timestamps as needed, calculate the densities, and compare against the cutoff value.

This way we know on the 1 minute level, whether we are in the Confidence Interval or not.

The code

(it is assumed that the code in the question has been run)

```
quantile <- qvonmises((1 - 0.95)/2, mu = periodic_mean, kappa = concentration)
cutoff <- dvonmises(quantile, mu = periodic_mean, kappa = concentration)

## generate a timestamp for every minute in a day
## then the transformations needed
ts_1min <- format(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), 
                             as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1), 
                             by = "1 min"), 
                  "%H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
ts_1min_hrs <- as.numeric(hms(ts_1min)) / 3600
ts_1min_hrs_circ <- circular(ts_1min_hrs, units = "hours", template = "clock24")
## generate densities to compare with the cutoff
dens_1min <- dvonmises(ts_1min_hrs_circ, mu = periodic_mean, kappa = concentration)
 
## compare: vector of FALSE/TRUE
feat_1min <- dens_1min >= cutoff
df_1min_feat <- data.frame(ts = ts_1min_hrs_circ, 
                             feature = feat_1min)

## get the min and max time of the CI
CI <- df_1min_feat %>% 
  filter(feature == TRUE) %>%
  summarise(min = min(ts), max= max(ts))

CI
#   min      max
# 5.283333 14.91667
```

With the information above, and using `geom_rect()`, we can get what we want:

```
ggplot(data.frame(timestamps_hrs_circ), aes(x = timestamps_hrs_circ)) +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_x_continuous("", limits = c(0, 24), breaks = seq(0, 24), minor_breaks = NULL) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(CI), color = "darkgreen", linetype = 1, size = 1.5) +
  geom_rect(xmin = CI$min, xmax = CI$max, ymin = 0, ymax = 5, alpha = .5, fill = "lightgreen") +
  ggtitle(label = "Circular Histogram", subtitle = "periodic mean in red,\n95%-CI in green" ) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 24), colour = "blue", fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(periodic_mean), color = "red", linetype = 2, size = 1.5) +
  theme_light()
```

Resulting in the following graph:

[image]

I hope someone may benefit from this as well.